# How to get product details sort/filter by color in Amazon API?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working Amazon API integration.I am also send request and get response.But i need to sort/filter by **color**.I am using this code for get response value.

```
$request = aws_signed_request('com', array(
'Operation' => 'ItemSearch',
'Keywords' => $keywords,
"SearchIndex" => $search_index,
"MaximumPrice" => $highprice,
"MinimumPrice" => $lowprice,
"Color" => $color,
"Count" => '24',"Brand" => $brand,
"MerchantId" => $MerchantId,
'ResponseGroup' => 'Large,EditorialReview'), $public_key, $private_key, $associate_tag);
```

In that coding, i need to filtered by color in amazon products.How is it possible? please advice me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/USSortValuesArticle.html), sorting by color is not currently supported

Edit: Neither is [filtering by color](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html)